# Где метод Table<T> Update?

Tags: c#, ado.net, repository, linq2sql

Использую дженерик репозиторий в проекте и и не могу понять как реализовать редактирование модели? Использую ado.net и нигде не могу найти информацию везде ef.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected Table<T> DataTable;

    public Repository(DataContext context)
    {
        DataTable = context.GetTable<T>();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DataTable.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public void Edit(T entity)
    {
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DataTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DataTable;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DataTable.Single(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DataTable.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Перестаньте обманывать себя и используйте EF. Потому что он у вас и так везде.

Comment: например где???

Comment: `DataContext` - это же контекст EF? И в других ваших сообщениях на сущности навешаны атрибуты EF.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Я не говорю, что это плохо. Сделать репозиторий поверх EF - это нормальная цель. Просто нужно так и писать в вопросах: "репозиторий поверх EF". А не "репозиторий с помощью чистого ADO.NET".

Comment: Это по вашему атрибут ef? вместо того что бы умничать лучше бы помогли, а на сущнасти навешаны потому что без них не работает....

Comment: Ok, это Linq to Sql - предшественник EF. Но суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: @Kioshilol, А почему у Table, должен быть метод Update? Поймите, Table скорее всего в ADO, это просто структура/класс интерпретации данных, а не бд. Вам нужно послать запрос в бд, на обновление таблицы, если не ошибаюсь, я вам уже отвечал, в одном из ваших вопросов, по поводу Adapter'a. Не залажу в код ( с телефона сижу ), посмотреть может у контекста есть метод Update или аналог.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Автор реально не понимает разницы, я уже [пробовал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002909/213987). Топикстартеру: во-первых, вам не "умничают", а пытаются донести правильное знание и исправить нестыковки у вас в голове, за которые вы цепляетесь по привычке. Во-вторых, в EF _уже_ реализованы репозитории (DbSet<>) и многие другие полезные вещи (UoW) и действительно очень часто в проектах делают свои собственные репозитории поверх репозиториев из коробки. Настоятельно рекомендую сделать мини-решение на EF, а потом попробовать этот EF убрать, это для вас будет очень полезно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы [DeleteOnSubmit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.itable-1.deleteonsubmit?view=netframework-4.8), [InsertOnSubmit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.itable-1.insertonsubmit?view=netframework-4.8) на самом деле не удаляют и не вставляют данные в БД. Они лишь *помечают* сущности как удалённые или вставленные. А реальный запрос в БД на удаление или вставку происходит при вызове метода [DataContext.SubmitChanges](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges?view=netframework-4.8).

Как происходит обновление (update) в Linq to Sql. Когда свойства сущности меняют свои значения: `someEntity.SomeProp = "someValue";` - эта сущность *помечается* как изменённая. А далее, аналогично, нужно вызвать метод `SubmitChanges` - при этом в БД будет послан реальный запрос.

---

Следовательно, в вашем репозитории должен быть метод, обычно он зовётся `Save`, который будет выполнять запрос(ы) к БД:

```
public void Save()
{
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Этот метод вызывайте после методов `Delete`, `Insert` и изменения свойств сущностей. Метод `Edit` при этом не нужен.

---

Как вариант, можно сделать так:

```
public void Delete(T entity)
{
    DataTable.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}

public void Insert(T entity)
{
    DataTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}

public void Edit() // хотя название Update тут будет лучше
{
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

В этом варианте метод `Save` не нужен. Но семантика `Edit` выглядит плохо: совершенно неясно, что его нужно вызвать после изменения свойств сущностей.